# empty space below body and weird placement of divs

Tags: html, css

I'm making a webpage for a friends site. you can find it here :

http://labrostest.byethost8.com/

my problems are the following:

1. I get a huge white empty space bellow my body div and also the division name lower_body is way to big with no apparent reason (at least for my eyes :P)
2. When using chrome the gallery section in the lower page is not positioned correctly- meaning just bellow the youtube video and show dates (I don't have the same problem on the firefox display).

can someone offer a helping hand.

do you need me to post my css and html code ?

Comment: thats strange...just clicked the link and i visited it o.O. are you sure you cant see it ?

Comment: Might want to clean up the errors too http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Flabrostest.byethost8.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Use Firefox and download the Firebug add-on, then use that to tweak your CSS until you get things looking exactly the way you want them. It helps a LOT (though you will want to test in other browsers as well.)

CSS is tricky - you've got the big gap at the bottom of your page, and in Chrome I see horizontal scrolling and a blank space off to the right.

Answer (score 3):

In you stylesheet there is a seloctor called lower_content. Please find this class and replace your block with this block. A blank space is coming because of unnecessary bottom space used which is used here.

```
.lower_content {
width: 800px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: relative;
bottom: 80px;
right: 30px;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: my friend thank you very much. It almost fixed the problem. The lower empty space nearly vanished (just some pixels now) however the entire lower content div repositioned further down in the page.

Comment: @LabrosPapageorgiou You can change the bottom position as per your requirement and one suggestion if you are agree with the solution or the provided solution helps you out. You must accept the answer and mark it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your `bottom` heights, they are way off, like `.lower_content` has 680px to bottom, is way to big. Instead use a smaller margin-bottom, and be sure to clear things after you have floated them

Answer (score 0):

You need to brush up on your css. Your bottom white space is a margin related issue with the body, and as for your gallery,  you said it, it's not positioned correctly so you have a cross browser compatibility issue that is probably something as simple as adding a browser specific css tag, or just readjusting your margins / paddding on the gallery section.

Answer (score 0):

You use relative positioning to overlap the elements. This changes where the element is displayed, but it will still take up space where it would have been without the relative displacement. That explains why you have a large empty area at the bottom of the page. Rather use a container that has `position:relative` but no displacement, and use elements with `position:absolute` inside it to overlay them.

The `lower_content` and the `gallery` elements are not large enough to contain the `gallery_text` element, so it sticks out below them. That is probably what is causing the extra white space below the body element, i.e. its original position before relative displacement would be outside the body element.

---

Also:

You have `margin:0` on the body element, but you should also have `padding:0` as some browsers (i.e. Opera) uses padding for the default padding of the body instead of margin.

There is a style element in the body element, which should be in the head element instead. That is not likely to cause any problem, but it's safer to put it where it should be according to the standard.