# How to get rid of extra space both horizontally and vertically in my html page

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4, whitespace

[image]Currently I am working on a home page with 70% of it covered with a carousel and 30% with a filter box component. I am facing a whitespace or blank unwanted space with the below code:

```
// SCSS
.home-box {
  .left-col {
     padding: 0;
     width: 100%;

      .img-box {
        display: flex;
      }
      img {
        background-position: center;
        background-size: contain;
        object-fit: contain;
        width: 80%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .carousel-item {
        display: block !important;
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        visibility: hidden;
      }
    .carousel-item.active {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  .right-col {
    width:30%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
   }
 }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="container-fluid home-box">
 <div class="row">
<div class="left-col col-12 col-lg-8">
  <ngb-carousel [showNavigationArrows]="false" [showNavigationIndicators]="false">
    <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let item of itemList">
      <div class="img-box">
        <img [src]="item.imgUrl">
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-carousel>
</div>
<div class="right-col col-12 col-lg-4">
  <filter-box></filter-box>
</div>
```

I am getting extra space and scroll bars are getting added both horizontally and vertically to bottom right corner of my page. 
I don't want to use `overflow:hidden` to my page. I have my global scss as below:

```
body, html {
  height:100% ;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
}
```

I have also checked below stack overflow threads as my content might be less for the page but if I add more contents - the space is getting increased.

1. [extra white space below the footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636664/extra-white-space-below-the-footer)
   2.[empty space below body and weird placement of divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824021/empty-space-below-body-and-weird-placement-of-divs)

I have also search a lot to find whether my positioning is a problem but finally I am unable to find the problem in my code. Can you guys please help me out?

Comment: Can you create a simplified HTML example?

Comment: + for @Zim's comment. Or, at least, screenshots?

Comment: Yes I am trying to create a fiddle, if not i will attach the screenshot in a moment

Comment: I have tried to create a fiddle but it needed lot of dependencies. So i created a mock up like how it is looking. Please consider this and help!

Comment: Can you replace carousel and filter with placeholder divs and get the same result? If so - could you try to add jsfiddle again w/o unneeded dependencies?

Comment: From what I see in a CSS - you using `100% width` for left-col instead of `70%`, therefore, your layout is `130%` width. As of height - there are no `height: 100%` set for other blocks except of image, so image will have 100% height of the parent (which is obviously not 100% of the screen).

Comment: Yes, body is 100% height, but the nested node of the body is not.